# Using Controls in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using Leafler to create a map for a video game (Arma 3). I already created some markers and layers but now I would like to create a control panel to display or no the layers on my map.

Here is my code from the app.js. Could someone help me to find the right procedure to add the controll panel with checkboxes.

````
var map = L.map('map', {
    crs: L.CRS.Simple,
});

//Map coordinates definition
var bounds = [[0,0], [307,307]];
var image = L.imageOverlay('assets/my_map_resized.png', bounds).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(bounds);

//Icons definitions(DRUGS)
var alcool_icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl :'assets/icons/alcool.png',
    iconSize: [25,40]
});

var artefact_icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl:'assets/icons/artefact.png',
    iconSize: [25,40]
});

var coke_icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl:'assets/icons/coke.png',
    iconSize: [25,40]
});

var dealers_icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl:'assets/icons/dealers.png',
    iconSize: [25,40]
});

var hero_icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl:'assets/icons/hero.png',
    iconSize: [25,40]
});

var meth_icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl:'assets/icons/meth.png',
    iconSize: [25,40]
});

var weed_icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl:'assets/icons/weed.png',
    iconSize: [25,40]
});

//Icons definitions(HOUSES)
var taudis_icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl:'assets/icons/taudis.png',
    iconSize: [25,40]
});

var house_icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl:'assets/icons/maison.png',
    iconSize: [25,40]
});

var storage_icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl:'assets/icons/hangar.png',
    iconSize: [25,40]
});

//Markers definitions (DRUGS)
var dealer1Marker = new L.Marker([ 215.2, 117.5 ], {icon: dealers_icon}).bindPopup("<b>Dealer 1</b><br>Coordonnees : 116.214<br><img src='assets/drugs_img/dealer1.jpg' style='width: 200px'>");
var dealer2Marker = new L.Marker([ 197.9, 201.4 ], {icon: dealers_icon}).bindPopup("<b>Dealer 2</b><br>Coordonnees : 201.198<br><img src='assets/drugs_img/dealer2.jpg' style='width: 200px'>");
var weedMarker = new L.Marker([ 090.4, 204 ], {icon: weed_icon}).bindPopup("<b>Traitement de Weed</b><br>Coordonnees : 203.090<br><img src='assets/drugs_img/weed_traitement.jpg' style='width: 200px'>");
var cokeMarker = new L.Marker([ 68.7, 211 ], {icon: coke_icon}).bindPopup("<b>Traitement de Coke</b><br>Coordonnees : 211.068<br><img src='assets/drugs_img/cocaine_traitement.jpg' style='width: 200px'>");
var heroineMarker = new L.Marker([ 193.4, 126.4 ], {icon: hero_icon}).bindPopup("<b>Traitement d'Heroine</b><br>Coordonnees : 126.193<br><img src='assets/drugs_img/heroine_traitement.jpg' style='width: 200px'>");
var alcoolMarker = new L.Marker([ 172.35, 39.1 ], {icon: alcool_icon}).bindPopup("<b>Traitement d'Alcool</b><br>Coordonnees : 039.172<br><img src='assets/drugs_img/alcool_traitement.jpg' style='width: 200px'>");
var methpurMarker = new L.Marker([ 203, 261 ], {icon: meth_icon}).bindPopup("<b>Traitement de Meth Pur</b><br>Coordonnees : 261.203<br><img src='assets/drugs_img/meth_traitement_pur.jpg' style='width: 200px'>");
var methimpurMarker = new L.Marker([ 096.7, 163.8 ], {icon: meth_icon}).bindPopup("<b>Traitement de Meth Impur</b><br>Coordonnees : 163.096<br><img src='assets/drugs_img/meth_traitement_impur.jpg' style='width: 200px'>");
var artefactMarker = new L.Marker([ 174.8, 098.7 ], {icon:artefact_icon}).bindPopup("<b>Acheteur d'Artefact</b><br>Coordonnees : 098.174<br><img src='assets/drugs_img/artefact_dealer.jpg' style='width: 200px'>");
var champcokeMarker = new L.Marker([ 146.3, 211.4 ], {icon: coke_icon}).bindPopup("<b>Champ de Cocaine</b><br>Coordonnees : 211.146<br><img src='assets/drugs_img/cocaine_recolte.jpg' style='width: 200px'>");
var kitmedMarker = new L.Marker([ 179.5, 67 ], {icon: meth_icon}).bindPopup("<b>Acheteur de Kit Medical</b><br>Coordonnees : 066.179<br><img src='assets/drugs_img/meth_kit.jpg' style='width: 200px'>");

//Markers definitions (HOUSES)
var house5M109134Marker = new L.Marker([ 134, 109 ], {icon: house_icon}).bindPopup("<b>Maison 5M</b><br><b>Position :</b> 109.134 Poliako<br><b>Proprietaire</b> Jack Senderson (Bled'Art)<br><b> Date :</b> 13.09.2020<br><b>GND pour infos :</b> Martinez/Tron/Heuss<br><b>Infos :</b> Sort de sa Maserati : WX-564-WF et rentre dans la maison / Deja perquisitionne / confirme proprio<br> <img src='assets/houses_img/house5M109134.jpg' style='width: 200px'>");
var storage109127Marker = new L.Marker([ 127.8, 109.2 ], {icon: storage_icon}).bindPopup("<b>Entrepot</b><br><b>Position :</b> 109.127 Sud Poliako<br><b>Proprietaire</b> John Briz, Steven Smith (Peaky Blinders)<br><b> Date :</b> 13.09.2020<br><b>GND pour infos :</b> Martinez<br><b>Infos :</b> Information d'un ancien membre Peaky faisant de la Weed et de l'artefact/ recemment cambrio (18/09/2020)<br> <img src='assets/houses_img/storage109127.jpg' style='width: 200px'>");
var storage125153Marker = new L.Marker([153, 125 ], {icon: storage_icon}).bindPopup("<b>Entrepot</b><br><b>Position :</b> 125.153 Sud Lakka<br><b>Proprietaire</b> Alucard Gloom (Civil)<br><b> Date :</b> 13.09.2020<br><b>GND pour infos :</b> Martinez/ Tron/ Bélanger/ Heuss/ Ferathia <br><b>Infos :</b> Trafic d'héroine suite une perquisition : Armes Gang, Trafic d'héroine<br> <img src='assets/houses_img/storage125153.jpg' style='width: 200px'>");
var house35M166160Marker = new L.Marker([160, 166 ], {icon: house_icon}).bindPopup("<b>Maison 3.5M</b><br><b>Position :</b> 166.160 Anthrakia<br><b>Proprietaire</b> Lena Wounder (Civil)<br><b> Date :</b> 13.09.2020<br><b>GND pour infos :</b> Martinez<br><b>Infos :</b> Aucune<br> <img src='assets/houses_img/house35M166160.jpg' style='width: 200px'>");
var house5M109133Marker = new L.Marker([133, 109 ], {icon: house_icon}).bindPopup("<b>Maison 5M</b><br><b>Position :</b> 109.133 Poliako<br><b>Proprietaire</b> Inconnu <br><b> Date :</b> 13.09.2020<br><b>GND pour infos :</b> Martinez<br><b>Infos :</b> Potentiel maison au Peaky Blinders<br> <img src='assets/houses_img/house5M109133.jpg' style='width: 200px'>");
var house27M097158Marker = new L.Marker([158, 97 ], {icon: house_icon}).bindPopup("<b>Maison 3.7M</b><br><b>Position :</b> 097.158 Agios <br><b>Proprietaire</b>Bernard Thoulisse (Civil)<br><b> Date :</b> 13.09.2020<br><b>GND pour infos :</b Martinez/ Biloute/ Bélanger<br><b>Infos :</b> Plantation de Weed/ pas de rideau/déja perquisitionné<br> <img src='assets/houses_img/house27M097158.jpg' style='width: 200px'>");
var house5M187165Marker = new L.Marker([165, 187 ], {icon: house_icon}).bindPopup("<b>Maison 5M</b><br><b>Position :</b> 187.165 Rodopoli<br><b>Proprietaire</b>Mickael Lopito (Civil)<br><b> Date :</b> 13.09.2020<br><b>GND pour infos :</b> Martinez/ Bélanger<br><b>Infos :</b>Stockage de Patate suite à une filature<br> <img src='assets/houses_img/house5M187165.jpg' style='width: 200px'>");



//Layer groups definitions
var dealers = L.layerGroup([dealer1Marker, dealer2Marker]);
var weed = L.layerGroup([weedMarker]);
var coke = L.layerGroup([cokeMarker, champcokeMarker]);
var heroine = L.layerGroup([heroineMarker]);
var alcool = L.layerGroup([alcoolMarker]);
var meth = L.layerGroup([methpurMarker, methimpurMarker, kitmedMarker]);
var artefact = L.layerGroup([artefactMarker]);

//Layer groups definitions for everyone
var jackSenderson = L.layerGroup([house5M109134Marker]);
var johnBriz = L.layerGroup([storage109127Marker]);
var stevenSmith = L.layerGroup([storage109127Marker]);
var alucardGloom = L.layerGroup([storage125153Marker]);
var lenaWounder = L.layerGroup([house35M166160Marker]);
var inconnu = L.layerGroup([house5M109133Marker]);
var bernardThoulisse = L.layerGroup([house27M097158Marker]);
var mickaelLopito = L.layerGroup([house5M187165Marker]);

//Add layers groups to map
dealers.addTo(map);
weed.addTo(map);
coke.addTo(map);
heroine.addTo(map);
alcool.addTo(map);
meth.addTo(map);
artefact.addTo(map);

//Add layers groups to map for everyone
jackSenderson.addTo(map);
johnBriz.addTo(map);
alucardGloom.addTo(map);
lenaWounder.addTo(map);
inconnu.addTo(map);
bernardThoulisse.addTo(map);
mickaelLopito.addTo(map);```

Thank you ! 

Antoine
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into: [Leaflet Controls](https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/)

```
var overlayMaps = {
 "Jack Senderson" : jackSenderson,
 "johnBriz" : johnBriz,
 "alucardGloom" : alucardGloom,
 "inconnu" : inconnu,
}

L.control.layers(null, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I was searching to far away from that !